# Storage on HTC desire X

Tags: internal-storage

The internal storage on my phone is almost full. The storage screen tells me

- 2.77GB / 2.91 GB taken
- Apps 0.89GB
- Other 1.89 GB
- Available 138MB

What is this "other" and how can I clean it up? I already followed the steps of "make more space", it barely makes a difference.

Phone Storage then tells me 43.00MB / 1.09GB is taken.

And on the SD card I have 1.86GB / 14.72GB taken.

I have plenty of storage in various places yet when I try to install apps I'm unable to do so cause of "insufficient storage". How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

On the HTC Desire X the memory (you would think you get 4Gb, but you don't) the partitions are as follows:

> System is 940 MB,
>
> Data is 1 GB,   (This is what you get for your apps really)
>
> 'Phone' storage is 1 Gb
>
> 1 GB towards "internal SD".

Basically you only get 1Gb on the device for your apps.
You could use a micro SD card to expand your storage and move your pictures/music/media to it, and some apps still support App2SD functionality.

Keep in mind Chrome can run up to 300 Mb no problem, so a cache cleaner may well help you with storage.  [Lifehacker article on what to do if you run out of space.](http://lifehacker.com/5668980/what-should-i-do-when-my-android-runs-out-of-app-space)

You can't really mess with the other partitions without rooting and then partitioning your SD card with an EXT3/EXT4 partition and a ROM that supports Link2SD to 'trick' your phone into believing there is more internal memory. These partitions contain Android, HTC stuff, system apps, data partition etc. So you get 1GB in all (you have 138Mb left). `Other`above is the OS, HTC apps and other Android related things, that you have no access to (without a rooted device).