# How to clear all of this Bloatware that is insidiously being put on my phone?

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory, bloatware

As is probably a very regular question here, I have a Samsung Galaxy S5 Neo and I'm having problems with the amount of memory being clogged up by what I will assume is garbage. I have installed on my phone ES File Explorer and it helps with cleaning things up, but I'm consistently low on internal storage and as a result my phone is slowed down. I barely have any  documents or downloads on my phone. The largest set of files is pictures which take up 194.38 MB. Here is where the issue is, there is 9.72 GB being categorized as "Other". So the percentages are as follows:

- Picture: 194.38 MB
- Audio 103.99 KB
- Video 124.23 MB
- Document 8.68 MB
- APPs 6.34 MB
- Others 9.72 GB

It drives me up a wall because I don't save anything to my internal storage and always use my SD card. So I'm of the feeling that it is my provider and Samsung that have put a bunch of bloatware on my phone. So the question is how to find it and get rid of it all? Suggestions on a set of instructions I could follow? I feel there i no reason my phone should be this restricted for storage considering how I use it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Have you already checked with our [bloatware tag-wiki](/tags/bloatware/info)? Your question seems covered more than once, though I'm not 100% sure to what degree. 4 matching Q&As are directly linked from the wiki, [30 additional candidates via this search](/search?q=[bloatware]+remove+answers%3A1).

Comment: Yes I've taken a look at some of the articles and it does appear the answers there are sufficient. Should I delete the post?

Comment: If there's one other question which you'd consider a duplicate of yours, we could close this as duplicate. Might help others finding it easier. You know, different search terms and such. You could also mention multiple useful ones (and update the tag wiki if you thing that would be helpful).

Comment: Yes. One of the other posts I read was essentially a duplicate. So we could close this one.

Comment: Related: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526

Comment: Which one, @dc3rd, so I can mark it here?

Comment: @Izzy    this one:  https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/64008/storage-on-htc-desire-x

Comment: Thanks, marked!